# How to display error for field that haven't been "touched" on submit

Tags: html, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I've an angular login, with reactive form:

```
  public form = this.fb.group({
    email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
    name: ['', [Validators.required]],
  });
```

When I click on submit, I do the following:

```
  async createUser() {
    if (this.form.valid) {
      this.uiService.startBusyIndicator('Adding user...');
      try {
        await this.userSettingsService.createUser(this.form.get('name')?.value, this.form.get('email')?.value);

        this.messageService.add({ severity: 'success', summary: 'User added', detail: 'User added successfully' });
      } finally {
        this.uiService.stopBusyIndicator();
        this.form.reset();
      }
    } else {
      console.log('Marking everything as touched');
      this.form.markAllAsTouched();
    }
  }
```

Here is my form:

```
  <p-dialog header="Add user" [(visible)]="displayAddForm" [modal]="true">
    <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="createUser()">
      <div class="grid formgrid p-fluid">
        <div class="field mb-4 col-12">
          <label [for]="name" class="font-medium text-900"> {{ 'account.fields.name' | translate }}</label>
          <input required pInputText formControlName="name" #name />
          <app-field-errors
            [formField]="form.controls['name']"
            [fieldName]="'account.fields.name' | translate"></app-field-errors>
        </div>
        <div class="field mb-4 col-12">
          <label [for]="email">{{ 'account.fields.email' | translate }}</label>
          <input required pInputText formControlName="email" #email />

          <app-field-errors
            [formField]="form.controls['email']"
            [fieldName]="'account.fields.email' | translate"></app-field-errors>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid">
        <button pButton type="submit" class="col-6 col-offset-6">Add user</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </p-dialog>
```

When I click on submit with having nothing as input, nothing changes, my fields still have the ng-pristine and not the ng-dirty classes?

I also tried to call `this.form.markAsDirty();` but same result.

Comment: I think the issue is with `app-field-errors`. Run a quick test, replacing `app-field-errors` with  `<div *ngIf="form.controls['email'].touched && form.controls['email'].invalid">Email required</div>`

Comment: @Nehal But even the `input` doesn't get the ng-dirty class which are required to get the correct styles from NgPrime to be displayed(the red border).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While testing I found that if I type some letters and remove them from input fields, they do get highlighted in red, which led to me to the realization that `required` validator doesn't effect the input fields, if you don't mark them as `dirty`, when they are in `pristine` state.

So, if you mark them accordingly, it should work for you, as you can see in this simplified [Stacblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-selectbutton-demo-7w4yeq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

component.ts:

```
  form: FormGroup;
  displayAddForm = true;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      name: ['', [Validators.required]]
    });
  }

  async createUser() {
    if (this.form.valid) {
      alert('valid form');
    } else {
      console.log('Marking everything as touched');
      this.form.markAllAsTouched();

      for (const key of Object.keys(this.form.controls)) {
        if(this.form.controls[key].value.length === 0) {
          console.log('blank value');
          this.form.controls[key].markAsDirty();
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

component.html:

```
<p-dialog header="Add User" [(visible)]="displayAddForm" [modal]="true">
  <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="createUser()">
    <div class="grid formgrid p-fluid">
      <div class="field mb-4 col-12">
        <label [for]="name" class="font-medium text-900"> Name</label>
        <input required pInputText formControlName="name" #name />
        <div class="error"
          *ngIf="form.controls['name'].touched && form.controls['name'].invalid">Name required</div>
      </div>
      <div class="field mb-4 col-12">
        <label [for]="email">Email</label>
        <input required pInputText formControlName="email" #email />

        <div class="error"
         *ngIf="form.controls['email'].touched && form.controls['email'].invalid">Email required</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid">
      <button pButton type="submit" class="col-6 col-offset-6">Add user</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</p-dialog>
```

Result (after clicking Add User, without touching any of the input fields):
[image]

Comment: the iteration + markAsDirty did the trick, thank you!